# how to solve netCDF library : Attempt to convert between text & numbers

Tags: netcdf

I like to hear your suggestions for solving the netCDF library problem. When I use a program netcdf merge to combine several small netcdf files, I get the following messages:

The netCDF library has reported the following problem:

```
NetCDF: Attempt to convert between text & numbers
```

I stuck~~ Please let me know any suggestions. Thanks a lot.

The following is my log file:

```
imerge: Merging 61 npptot*.nc files, using 1 buffers

Number of dimensions:  4 
Dimension id:  0    Name:  longitude     Length:     4 
Dimension id:  1    Name:  latitude      Length:     1 
Dimension id:  2    Name:  time          Length:    60 
Dimension id:  3    Name:  lengthd       Length:    10 

Number of variables:  6 

Number of global attributes:  5 
Global attribute:  0     Attribute:  title           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  25   Value:  monthly total NPP carbon  
Global attribute:  1     Attribute:  source          Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  14   Value:  ibis wmonthly  
Global attribute:  2     Attribute:  history         Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  12   Value:  14-May-2012  
Global attribute:  3     Attribute:  calendar        Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  10   Value:  gregorian  
Global attribute:  4     Attribute:  conventions     Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  9    Value:  NCAR-CSM 
Variable:  longitude     Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  10   Value:  longitude 
Variable:  longitude     Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  13   Value:  degrees_east 

Attention: NetCDF attribute 'missing_value' does not exist for the selected variable. 
Variable:  latitude      Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  9    Value:  latitude 
Variable:  latitude      Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  14   Value:  degrees_north 

Attention: NetCDF attribute 'missing_value' does not exist for the selected variable. 
Variable:  time          Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  5    Value:  time 
Variable:  time          Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  22   Value:  days since 1500-12-31  

Attention: NetCDF attribute 'missing_value' does not exist for the selected variable. 
Variable:  time_weights  Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  29   Value:  number of days per time step 
Variable:  time_weights  Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  5    Value:  days 

Attention: NetCDF attribute 'missing_value' does not exist for the selected variable. 
Variable:  date          Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  25   Value:  label for each time step 
Variable:  date          Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  1    Value:   

Attention: NetCDF attribute 'missing_value' does not exist for the selected variable. 
Variable:  npptot        Attribute:  long_name       Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  16   Value:  total NPP carbon 
Variable:  npptot        Attribute:  units           Type:  NC_CHAR, string      Length:  14   Value:  kg-C/m^2/month 
Variable:  npptot        Attribute:  missing_value   Type:  NC_FLOAT, 4 bytes    Length:  1    Value:  9e+20 
Value of netCDF attribute 'missing_value' is:  9e+20 
In file npptot0.nc there is 1 nlat line for a running total of 1 latitude lines.
:
:
:
variable 0: longitude, rank 1, size 4
variable 1: latitude, rank 1, size 61
variable 2: time, rank 1, size 60
variable 3: time_weights, rank 1, size 60
variable 4: date, rank 2, size 600
```

Comment: Is the program `netcdf merge` or `ncmerge` from [getm-utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getm-utils/)?